# Every finite extension of the field with characteristics $0$ is simple extension.

Tags: abstract-algebra, splitting-field

We, know every splitting field a finite algebraic extension.

So, therefore every splitting field over the field with characteristics $0$ is a simple extension.

But, here I choose the irreducible polynomial $x^{3}-2 $ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Then , the splitting field of $x^{3}-2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt{-3}]$ ,

But , now how could this extension $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt{-3}]$ generated only by one element?

Also, how to show that Every finite extension of the field with characteristics $0$ is simple extension ?

Comment: See [Primitive element Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem).

Comment: See also [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3158363/how-to-compute-a-primitive-element-for-the-splitting-field-of-x3-2-in-bbbq).

Comment: Does $\sqrt[3]2\sqrt{-3}$ work?